# In the movie Elysium, was the locution used by the CEO to ask the robots to kill significant?

Tags: elysium

Have not seen the movie in a while but the CEO (who had interacted with Jodie Foster's character earlier) tells the robots something like, “*I am being followed by a man and I would like him dead.*”

I wonder if this is meant to be a nod to The Three Laws -- he could not explicitly tell them to kill a human but he could express a wish about things.

I guess 3 Laws is not exactly what I meant -- I am asking if the way the guy spoke to the robots reflected trying to avoid triggering some sort of interlock in the robots -- was there a reason he could not have simply said, "kill the men who are following me."?

Comment: I don't get it. What would the Three Laws have to do with it? The Three Laws are rules governing the behavior of robots. They are not restrictions on how a human can talk to his robots.

Comment: Not exactly 3 Laws -- mainly wondering if the reason he said it that way was an indication that the writer thought you could not explicitly command a robot to kill.

Comment: Why would a robot reject an order to kill, but follow a vaguely expressed wish, if killing is not allowed?  Only thing I can see is the guy trying to avoid legal problems using a (very) thin fig leaf.  "But, your honor, I didn't order the man killed.  I just wished he were dead, and the robot got carried away and killed him without being told to." Thin ice.

Comment: Also, the three laws come from Isaac Asmov's works, which Elysium is *not* one of.  There's no reason given in the movie to believe these robots are beholden to anything like Asimov's Laws of Robotics.

Comment: @Steve-O: again, my question is was the way the guy requested that the robots kill the men significant or would he have gotten the same results by explicitly asking the robots to kill the men. Was the writer thinking of some sort rules that the robots are constrained by that made him have to ask that way.

Comment: @JRE: that is possible, certainly robots that kill without explicit requests are worse than robots that respond to direct requests.

Answer (score -2):

I think the way the executive asked the robots to deal with his pursuers is significant. Probably the laws for immortal (note that Jody's character spoke of renewing his contract for 2 frigging centuries) CEOs of major companies are enforced "inconsistently" when they occasionally end up doing something which results in the deaths of non-immortals. (Who after all will die relatively soon anyway.)

His phraseology definitely leaves out an explicit "kill" order and perhaps also gave the robots the flexibility of not killing but potentially having the pursuers arrested if the situation allowed it. Not that this exec gave the slightest about such people -- a theme in cyberpunk is this gulf and we will see what happens in real life pretty soon.

The choices are either everyone benefits from advanced AI/robotics or only a tiny portion (like the top .001 percent, literally one in 100,000 because such satellites like Elysium I am guessing are extremely limited in capacity relative to the world population, even if there were 100 or 1000 of them which I suspect would not work -- maybe Elysium was meant to be the only one, the pinnacle of existence for maybe tops 10,000 people so indeed one in a million.

(If he made a sequel, I would sure like to know more about life on Elysium, perhaps the incredible fear some guy has about losing his job and being forced to live in a slum on Earth again.)

Comment: You claim it is, but don't give any evidence for that.

Comment: @releseabe to be clear: the thing about this website is that it's not meant for debate or discussion (regardless of how interesting). Speculation is meant to be kept at a minimum (as much as this makes sense when discussing scifi, anyway), and instead you're supposed to back your answers with references to the source material that support it. Instead of "my opinion..." or "I think that..." it should be "it is like this, as stated by the author in <link>" or "the script clearly states that <fact>".